# tabular: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tables

The following piece of code works and compiled, when I change the `\pagestyle{empty}` to `\pagestyle{plain}` in the following style file for resume.

https://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls

```
\documentclass[overlapped, 12pt]{res}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}

\reversemarginpar
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.in}
\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{2.in}%
\usepackage[hmargin=1.0in, bottom=0.5in, top=0.5in]{geometry}
\errorcontextlines 10000
\begin{document}

\begin{resume}
\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip 

\section{EDUCATION}
\begin{tabular}[t] {@{} p{\textwidth}p{\rcollength} lcr}
PhD in Physics, Syracuse University, Syracuse, NY, USA & 2006-2009\\
{\sl Title} & \\\\
\end{tabular}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

However, as soon as I try to adjust the width of first column

```
\begin{tabular}[t] {@{} p{\textwidth-\rcollength}p{\rcollength} lcr}
```

I get a compilation error:

```
./cv_sadia.tex:53: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
\@startpbox ...vtop \bgroup \setlength \hsize {#1}
                                                  \@arrayparboxrestore 
<template> ...startpbox {\textwidth -\rcollength }
                                                  \ignorespaces 
<to be read again> 
                   P
l.53 P
      hD in Physics, Syracuse University, Syracuse, NY, USA & 2006-2009\\
```

If I keep the pagestyle empty, then there is no error. Any help is appreciated, as I do want to keep page number displayed on each page.

Answer (score 3):

Should be:

```
 p{\dimexpr\textwidth-\rcollength}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I appreciate if you can explain it as well.

Comment: only with package `calc` you can have expressions of lengths. But `res.cls` doesn't load package `calc`. However, using macro `\dimexpr` is the better choice.